# "Iterator not dereferenceable"

Tags: c++, iterator, runtime, runtime-error, dereference

I love when code gives me headaches. Except this one. I am simply filling a vector with random doubles using an often used algorithm. The problem is, after it compiles, it gives me a "Iterator not dereferenceable" runtime error. Here is my code path:

-First I create an instance of a class.

```
 Random rm;
```

-Which runs this constructor

```
    Random::Random() // Constructor
{
    this->cAR();
    this->min = 0; // Default: Sets minimum to zero
    this->max = RAND_MAX; // Default: Sets maximum to RAND_MAX

    fillVect(); // Fills vector
    this->numCount = num.begin();
}
```

-cAR simply sets some values in below function

```
void Random::cAR()
{
    this->num.clear();
    this->num.reserve(250);
    this->place = 0;
}
```

-Now for the main problem (I think), I iterate thru the vector and fill it with random numbers generated

```
void Random::fillVect()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<double>::iterator counter;
    for (counter = this->num.begin(); counter <= num.end(); counter++)
    {
        *counter = (((double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * (this->max - this->min)) + this->min;
    }

    shuffle();
}
```

-That should fill the vector (which is a "double" type vector, btw) with random numbers. Then, I call the next number in the vector (which should be the 0th index at the beginning) with this statement

```
double r = rm.nextDbl();
```

-Which is defined in this function

```
double Random::nextDbl()
{
    double temp = *numCount;
    return temp;
    numCount++;
    place++;
}
```

In my head, this is a correct code path. Now, I've only been coding for 2 years, and only 1 year as a student at an actual college, so my question would be, why is it giving me this runtime error? I appreciate any help beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing the `end()` iterator, which is invalid:

```
 for (counter = this->num.begin(); counter <= num.end(); counter++)
```

This should be:

```
for (counter = this->num.begin(); counter != num.end(); ++counter)
```

Comment: But why ++counter? Aren't I supposed to assign a random number to the first index and then increase the index place? Why does the counter have to be incremented beforehand?

Comment: Prefer pre-increment over post-increment.  There are probably an umpteen threads on SO and in your favorite C++ book as to why this is the case.

Comment: Still no dice. I've replaced both the counter and the condition, and have also used resize instead of reserve, so I'm out of luck. Maybe ill just redo the whole thing, see how that turns out.

Comment: @user3338383 - Your code still has to have the changes mentioned.  You just happen to have another error somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code. First: you are dereferencing the `end()` iterator in your loop

```
for (counter = this->num.begin(); counter <= num.end(); counter++)
//                                        ^^ should be less than
```

Second: your `num` vector is empty so once you fix the first problem you will just end up with no numbers:

```
this->num.clear();       // num is now empty
this->num.reserve(250);  // num is still empty
```

I think you meant to call `resize(250)` instead of `reserve(250)`. The latter just makes sure the vector has enough capacity... if it was already empty it will stay empty.

Also, two suggestions:

1. Consider using [std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) as a substitute for your loop. What you are doing is exactly generating values for `num`, so this algorithm will make it explicit to your readers.
2. Your approach to picking a random number is *not* uniform:

   `(((double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * (this->max - this->min)) + this->min;`

That will not produce a uniform distribution, even if `rand()` itself produced a uniform distribution... and this will pretty much never give you `this->max` as a value. A much better solution, would be:

```
int nextRandom() {
    int range = this->max - this->min + 1;
    int max_rand = RAND_MAX / range * range; // largest multiple of range under RAND_MAX
    for (;;) {
        int r = rand();
        if (r < max_rand) {
            return (r % range) + this->min;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would be the ideal place to resize the vector? Should it be in the constructor or in the fillVect() itself?

Comment: @user3338383 I'd put it in `fillVect()`. That's the most reasonable place.